# StatsD gauge timer send data issue - cannot send only one value to statsd server in one flush interval

Tags: akka, graphite, statsd

I use [Statsd client based on Akka IO](https://github.com/archena/statsd-akka) source code to send data to statsd server. In my scenario, I want to monitor spark jobs status, if current job success, we gonna send 1 to statsd server, otherwise 0. So in one flush interval I just wanna send one value (1 or 0) to statsd server, but it didn't work, If I added a for loop, and send this value(1 or 0) at least twice, it works, But I don't know why should I send the same value twice, so I checked the statsd source code, and found:

```
for (key in gauges) {
   var namespace = gaugesNamespace.concat(sk(key));
   stats.add(namespace.join(".") + globalSuffix, gauges[key], ts);
   numStats += 1;
 }
```

So the type of gauges should be the iterator, if I just send one value, It can not be iteratored, this is what I thought, maybe it is wrong, hope someone can help me explain why should I send one value at least twice.

My client code snippet:

```
  for(i<- 1 to 2) {
      client ! ExcutionTime("StatsD_Prod.Reporting."+name+":"+status_str+"|ms", status)
      Thread.sleep(100)
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the client code that you are using to send the value of the gauge? Also, can you explain what you mean by "it didn't work"? A gauge works by recording the last received value. So if you're sending the same metric from multiple machines it will override previously sent values.

Comment: @mrwillihog Thanks for comments, added the client code snippet, at this time, I tried the ExcutionTime, same as Timer.  "it didn't work" means the server didn't show any data in metrics, I just want to send one value and it is from one machine.  send twice works for me, but just send once, it will not show the data in the metrics, so I want to know what is the reason.

Comment: Thanks - that code looks like a timer, not a gauge? Gauges end with `|g`. Is your metric appearing in the timers section?

Comment: @mrwillihog yes, I use Timer in my code, It will work if I send them twice for both Gauge and Timer.  it won't work for sending once for both of them.

Comment: Hmm, you can start StatsD with a console backend and make sure it is receiving the metrics. Usually, in StatsD clients you dont have to specify the type (i.e. `|ms`). Are you sure the `ExecutionTime` method isn't adding `|ms` for you?

Comment: @mrwillihog ok, thanks, i checked the ExecutionTime method, it added `|ms`.